# AngularJS Reusability with deferred and promise

Tags: angularjs, ajax, promise, deferred

I am beginner using the deferred promise and could not find exact answers for the questions I have.

- Deferred promise is really recommended even for single simple ajax($http angularjs) call? I know it is good if we have many ajax calls in sequence or same time.
- Second question is about reusability. I have an ajax call to rest service in default page loading to show a list of items. When the filter drop down gets changed, then want to call same method in service for reusing it. But it brings same result as earlier, so I had to use completely different one. Code is given below. Is there any way for reusing the original method.

Controller: Similar methods but I need to have different promises.

```
$scope.applyReportFilter = function(){
    $log.log($scope.period);
    $scope.periodData = {periodType:$scope.period.id};
    var promisT = rptSvc.getAllReportE($scope.periodData);
    promisT.then(function(resultW){
        $scope.resultReport = resultW;
        $log.log("Rpt filter" + resultW);
    }).then(function(errorT){
        $scope.result = errorT;
    });
}
var promis = rptSvc.getAllReport($scope.periodData);
    //$log.log($scope.data.period);
    promis.then(function(result){
        $scope.resultReport = result;
        $log.log("Rpt" + result);
    }).then(function(error){
        $scope.result = error;
    });
```

Service: For applying filter I had to use another method to have different deferred.

```
var dfrdE = $q.defer();
report.getAllReportE=function(prd){
    $log.log(prd.periodType);
    $http.post(URLs.AllReportURL,prd)
    .success(function(respE){
        dfrdE.resolve(respE);
    }).error(function(respE){
        dfrdE.reject(respE);
    });

    return dfrdE.promise;
}
var dfrd = $q.defer();
report.getAllReport=function(prd){
    $log.log(prd.periodType);
    $http.post(URLs.AllReportURL,prd)
    .success(function(respGR){
        dfrd.resolve(respGR);
    }).error(function(respGR){
        dfrd.reject(respGR);
    });

    return dfrd.promise;
}
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have managed to do two [Promise anti-patterns](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) in your code.

- [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) returns a `$q` promise in itself, you are just wrapping it up in another promise.
- When needed, use `$q(..` instead of `$q.defer` because the revealing constructor pattern has a nicer, conciser syntax (doesn't need an extra deferred variable) and also catches exceptions from the resolver callback. .

I do not exactly understand what you are trying to convey in second part of question, but you can reduce both service calls to simply be:

```
report.getAllReport=function(prd){
    $log.log(prd.periodType);
    return $http.post(URLs.AllReportURL,prd);
}
```

Comment: The mistake in the second part was creating the deferreds outside of the functions which use them. This results in the same (fulfilled) promise being returned on subsequent calls, rather than a new one being created. Of course, nuking the deferred anti-pattern resolves this issue.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are not two anti-patterns but one anti-pattern twice. Also `$q.defer` and other forms of promise creation cannot be completely outlawed - they are necessary (in different circumstances) for "promisification" of non promise-returning async functions.

Comment: Thanks @mido for the quick answer. My Second question is to reusing the  already used method. I have a method to call Rest service when the page loads. I want to use same method but with different values in an event - applyfilter - without creating new defer & promise.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I have nothing against promisifcation of async call, my problem is usage of `$q.defer` instead of `$q(..`, Bergi's reason for this:  Basically because the revealing constructor pattern has a nicer, conciser syntax (doesn't need an extra deferred variable) and also catches exceptions from the resolver callback.

Comment: @Mido, your bullet point "Do not use $q.defer, it is deffered anti-pattern" doesn't reflect those points and is very misleading.